# Finding row until condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table:

| PackingNr | SerienNr |
| --- | --- |
| PN185971 | PN185972 |
| PN185972 | PN185974 |
| PN185974 | PN185978 |
| PN185978 | R005478 |
| PN185968 | R000547 |
| PN185725 | R004987 |

As an input I get `PackingNr` and I need to select `SerienNr` which is like Rxxxxx not PNxxxxx.

So for example, if I have input `PN175971`, I need to get `SerienNr = R005478`.

How can I do this inside of select query? I tried `CASE` but this won't work as I don't know how many times I have to go again.

My select query is selecting also other columns from different tables.

```
SELECT 
    ...  ,
    CASE 
        WHEN PSPD.SerienNr LIKE '%PN%' 
            THEN 
                (SELECT SerienNr FROM PSAPacking_Det 
                 WHERE PSAPacking_Det.PackingNr = PSPD.SerienNr) 
            ELSE PSPD.SerienNr 
    END AS SerienNr
    ...
FROM 
    PSAPacking PSPD
JOIN 
     ...
WHERE 
   PSPD.PackingNr = 'PN185971'
```

Comment: It is not clear how you pick a (PN185978, R005478) row based on a PN175971 value

Comment: I have to use the connection between the two columns. If PN185971 has PN185972  then I have to search PN185972 as PackingNr and I get serienNr PN178974 and this I have to do until I get the R005478 as SerienNr.

Comment: use a recursive CTE

Comment: Thank you Wouter for your help, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE. Something like this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.PackingNr, t.SerienNr
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t..PackingNr = 'YourValueHere'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.PackingNr, t.SerienNr
    FROM YourTable t
    JOIN cte ON cte.SerienNr = t.PackingNr
)
SELECT TOP (1)
  *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.SerienNr LIKE 'R%';
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I used this and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare @var2 varchar(max) = 'PN185971' --PUT YOUR INPUT HERE
declare @var1  varchar(max);

while(@var2 not like 'R%')
begin
    set @var1 = @var2
    set @var2  = (select max(SerienNr) from PSAPacking where PackingNr = @var1)
end

select @var2
```

if it doesn't find the value starting with R it returns null

Comment: It works, but it's not ideal for my case, but thanks anyway.